# Rails 3 Listing ActiveRecord objects alphabetically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can i create a queryset and view (@contacts in my situation) in Rails 3 to list ActiveRecord objects alphabetically?

I'm trying to do this implementation;

A ->
 Contacts starts with A

B ->
 Contacts starts with B etc.

Final look:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/lists/lists-divider.html

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to do something like this:

```
@users = User.all.group_by{|u| u.name[0]}
```

In the view:

```
<% @users.keys.sort.each do |starting_letter| %>
  <%= starting_letter %>
  <% @users[starting_letter].each do |user| %>
    <%= user.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How would you create a link to all of the users that start with "F" and display this on a separate page?

Answer (score 6):

Fetch all contacts from DB and use `enum.group_by` method on the array:

```
@contacts = Contact.order(:name)
@contacts.group_by{ |contact| contact.name[0] }.each do |contact|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Cool answer thanks, this approach works actually but in my implementation i need to nested view loops "by start name" and "by contact name" because JQuery mobile holds first letter and object names as different css classes

Answer (score 1):

When I do alphabetized results, I create a separate column (e.g. `first_letter`) to hold the first letter of the name, or "#" when the first character is not a letter. (I generally do this when I'm only showing one letter at a time, so if you're not querying by first letter this is probably overkill.)

Your controller code would look like `@contacts = Contact.all.order('first_letter, name').group_by(&:first_letter)`

A simple (HAML) view could look like this (I'm not quickly seeing what kind of output jQuery mobile wants):

```
- (['#'] + ('A'..'Z').to_a).each do |letter|
  %h2 #{letter}
  %ol
    - if !@contacts[letter].empty?
      - @contacts[letter].each do |contact|
        %li #{contact.name}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will get you home, unless I misunderstand what you want...

```
@contacts.order(:name).group(:name)
```

At this moment in time @contacts is not the list of results, but is an iterator that will execute sql when you first try to use it to get results (.each, .count, etc).

here's a really great guide on this area: [ActiveRecord querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: This will stick a `GROUP BY` clause in the SQL query. This will cause records with the same `name` to have all but the first ignored, which isn't the goal.

Comment: I misunderstood then :P Completely. I don't do things by halves, I guess.  I think in retrospect, Semyon's answer is the way to go.